# Burn the stackexchange tag on the main site

Tags: discussion, tags

Personally, I cannot think of a single question that would be on topic that uses that tag, and the questions currently tagged with this tag reflect that.

Comment: I see 0 questions tagged [tag:stackexchange].

Comment: When you write *burn*, do you mean *ban*?

Comment: There's really no reason to _ban_ it. I don't think it gets accidentally used often enough to be a problem. This seems kind of like a non-issue, personally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've cleared all questions on the tag. I don't believe there's a need to ban or blacklist the tag there were just 6 questions and any future questions are going to be rare.